# Measuring Stokes parameters leading to a degree of polarisation greater than one

Tags: optics, measurements, polarization

I am trying to measure the stokes parameters of a laser beam using the rotating waveplate method detailed here:

https://pol3he.sites.wm.edu/wp-content/uploads/sites/50/2020/01/measuring-Stokes-parameters.pdf

The relevant equations are

[image: Equation 1]

[image: Equation 2]
[image: Equation 3]
[image: Equation 4]
[image: Equation 5]

The laser wavelength is 355nm, and the QWP is also designed for 355nm - https://www.thorlabs.com/thorproduct.cfm?partnumber=WPQ05M-355

However, when I calculate the parameters S0 often ends up being smaller than some or all of S1, S2 and S3, leading to a degree of polarisation much greater than one, which seems to be obviously nonsense.

I have triple checked the maths in the paper and the experimental setup, and I'm pretty sure what I'm doing is the same as what is detailed in the paper, and also this youtube video by Thorlabs based on the paper: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pR4r7gMyN5U&t=688s.

Is the paper wrong, or is there some subtle thing that I'm missing that needs to be taken into account when measuring Stokes parameters? Can I just ignore the crazy high degree of polarisation and say "That is effectively 1"? If I add an offset angle to the measured angle then the results I get for degree of polarisation change, but a) this feels like a fudge, and b) I aligned my polariser and QWP 0 position to the horizontal axis as best I could so any offset angle should only be small.

I don't know how to link my data, but here is a table of three different measurements I took (all in mW, and under different input polarisations so they shouldn't be the same).

| Angle | Measurement 1 | Measurement 2 | Measurement 3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 270 | 447 | 660 |
| 20 | 60 | 256 | 550 |
| 40 | 29 | 20 | 220 |
| 60 | 255 | 72 | 13 |
| 80 | 331 | 262 | 80 |
| 100 | 393 | 248 | 209 |
| 120 | 211 | 60 | 251 |
| 140 | 25 | 80 | 305 |
| 160 | 96 | 316 | 490 |
| 180 | 291 | 432 | 660 |

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can you include the calculation of how you go from this data to the degree of polarization?  Also, have you made sure you've normalized the data properly/

Comment: The calculations are in the paper I linked, but I can reproduce them in the text if you want

Comment: @EdV: I did try that for Measurement 1 - I got a degree of polarisation of 1.1, which is better than 14 and possibly within the error of the measurement, however the stokes parameters are very different. I might try it again either this afternoon or on Monday –

Comment: @JQK: How would you suggest normalising? I could divide by the power measured without the QWP/polariser, or I could divide by the max of each measurement, but neither of those will affect the degree of polarisation

Comment: Thanks @EdV, it's nice to see that confirmed. Do you have a link to the software you are using? It would be useful to be able to run simulations like that myself

Comment: @EdV Thanks for your help, it's nice to know at least one thing is correct. I have done some playing about with my data and found that if I add an angle of 50 degrees to my QWP angle then my results suddenly start to make sense. I can't explain where this angle comes from, as both polarisation elements should be aligned to the horizontal, but so far it seems to make the results accord with reality.

Comment: @EdV You are right, there is a QWP and a HWP before the polarimeter, and also an attenuator which I believe consists of another HWP and a linear polariser. I didn't include them as this system should be able to measure the polarisation no matter what is in front of it, but I can make the edit today at some point.